# Como ler dados do teclado para uma matriz em Java?

Tags: java, matriz

Estou tentando passar os dados para dentro da matriz, porém não está correndo as linhas.

```
int i=0;
        int j=0;
        
        for(;i<3;i++){
            for(;j<4;j++){
                System.out.println("Valor para a posição ["+i+","+j+"]");
                notasAlunos[i][j]=entrada.nextDouble();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direto ao ponto:

Esta ocorrendo por que, na primeira iteração, ao sair do 2º laço for (  `for(;j<4;j++){` ) a variável `j` possui valor `4`, e este valor **não é reiniciado**, portanto na 2ª iteração `j=4`sendo assim não satisfazendo a condição e por conseguinte nem entrando no laço for.

Para corrigir atribua o valor `0` à variável `j` a cada nova iteração:

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.println("Valor para a posição ["+i+","+j+"]");
                notasAlunos[i][j]=entrada.nextDouble();
            }
```